# Count the no of Visitors

Tags: asp.net

I have stored resumes in my database and i have retrive it from asp.net web page by creating linkbutton...i can view ,download the resumes which i stored in my database.My issuse is when i view one resume example (domnic resume)then no of visitor for domnic resume should be count .if again i view that resume no of visitor should be 2...how can i do that in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to do this, each have their quirks.  Here is a quick and dirty way to do it, the only thing to remember is that the Session_OnEnd can be a bit flaky.

```
public void Application_OnStart(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Application["SESSION_LIST"];
    if(ht == null)
    {
      ht = new Hashtable();
      lock(Application)
      {
        Application["SESSION_LIST"] = ht;
        Application["TOTAL_SESSIONS"] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  public void Session_OnStart(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Application["SESSION_LIST"];
    if(ht.ContainsKey(Session.SessionID) == false)
    {
      ht.Add(Session.SessionID, Session);
    }

    lock(Application)
    {
      int i = (int)Application["TOTAL_SESSIONS"];
      i++;
      Application["TOTAL_SESSIONS"] = i;
    }
  }

  public void Session_OnEnd(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Session.Clear();
    Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Application["SESSION_LIST"];
    ht.Remove(Session.SessionID);

    lock(Application)
    {
      int i = (int)Application["TOTAL_SESSIONS"];
      i--;
      Application["TOTAL_SESSIONS"] = i;
    }

  }
```

Here's another way...

[Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902083/count-the-no-of-visitors)

Comment: This doesn't work when the site has a lot of ajax response pages. It will increase the TOTAL_SESSIONS variable for each ajax request/response.

Comment: I don't have this issue with WCF services using AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed.  The reason your getting this is probably caused by how you treat connections to your web services as stateless (each request = new connection).

Comment: implement `Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();` ?

Comment: @JonasT Session_OnStart and Ajax solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of no of views displayed by keeping the count in the database or a persistent storage of your choice. Whenever a particular resume view is requested, update the view count for that resume. You may disclose some elements of the design you have done to get more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see this count as a developer/admin, and you have interest in collecting stats site-wide, you may also look into using Google Analytics.