# Counts actual runs of same application

Tags: vb.net

I have a public web application and need to know (for statistics) how many simultaneous executions occurs. An example would be the equivalent of how many visitors are on a web page or how many users are connected into DB.

I think one way to achieve this is by registering users in a DB on Internet and count the records periodically. The problem with this, if the application loses connection to the Web or the OS crash, the application not send the code to subtract the count, giving false positives.

Please if you can give me a starting point to made this code.

Regards Amigos

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189600/how-to-count-number-of-visitors-for-website-in-asp-net-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389880/how-to-get-the-accurate-total-visitors-count-in-asp-net

Comment: You are going to need to define *precisely* what it is you are looking for, and *why* you are looking for it. You can work out "simultaneous executions" by looking at your request log files - you know when each request started and ended, so you can easily work out how many requests occurred for any given second/minute/hour whatever. However, this may, or may not, be useful information depending on what you need to know and why. Are you looking for "how many visitors do I have on my website", or "how many request per second am I serving", or something else?

Comment: Hello RB, just need to know how many simultaneous or concurrent executions are occurring with my application (vb.net) in different PCs for statistical purposes.

Comment: maybe i got your point. Example in login form. `How many users login to your page/system?` then the idea you have is when user login or someone, increment the counter in the DB else when user logout -1 to the count stored in DB but your main problem is how about if the user did not click logout or system shutdown. So the code for decrements will not execute and you will lose the counts of user inside of your system. Some thing like that you want to achieve?

Comment: Hell Muj, thank you for your answer. 

Your approach is an example for loged users, unfortunately my English is not enough to make me understand, also I am begginer as developer..

I'll try to describe my idea, I need know how many people are using my application in real time, no matter which countries the application is installed, the only condition is have access into the Web for increment / decrement the counter ...

I hope you understand me, thank in advance.